# Why is gems missing after 'bundle install' says it installs them?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, macos-ventura

Running `bundle install` in my project gives the following output:

```bash
➜  <my-project> git:(main) ✗ bundle install
Ignoring eventmachine-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine eventmachine --version 1.2.7
Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5
Ignoring http_parser.rb-0.8.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine http_parser.rb --version 0.8.0
Ignoring sassc-2.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine sassc --version 2.4.0
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
Using zeitwerk 2.5.4
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using bundler 2.3.11
Using coffee-script-source 1.11.1
Using colorator 1.1.0
Using minitest 5.15.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using execjs 2.8.1
Using commonmarker 0.23.4
Using unf_ext 0.0.8
Fetching eventmachine 1.2.7
Fetching http_parser.rb 0.8.0
Using faraday-em_http 1.0.0
Using faraday-excon 1.1.0
Using faraday-net_http_persistent 1.2.0
Using faraday-patron 1.0.0
Using faraday-rack 1.0.0
Using faraday-retry 1.0.3
Fetching ffi 1.15.5
Using faraday-net_http 1.0.1
Using forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Using gemoji 3.0.1
Using faraday-em_synchrony 1.0.0
Using rexml 3.2.5
Using rb-fsevent 0.11.1
Using ruby2_keywords 0.0.5
Using mercenary 0.3.6
Using safe_yaml 1.0.5
Using liquid 4.0.3
Using rouge 3.26.0
Using faraday-httpclient 1.0.1
Using racc 1.6.0
Using multipart-post 2.1.1
Using jekyll-paginate 1.1.0
Using webrick 1.7.0
Using rubyzip 2.3.2
Using jekyll-swiss 1.0.0
Using jekyll-commonmark 1.4.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using tzinfo 1.2.9
Using addressable 2.8.0
Using pathutil 0.16.2
Using kramdown 2.3.1
Using faraday-multipart 1.0.3
Using nokogiri 1.13.3 (arm64-darwin)
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using kramdown-parser-gfm 1.1.0
Using unicode-display_width 1.8.0
Using jekyll-coffeescript 1.1.1
Using activesupport 6.0.4.6
Using faraday 1.10.0
Using terminal-table 1.8.0
Using sawyer 0.8.2
Using unf 0.1.4
Using html-pipeline 2.14.0
Using octokit 4.22.0
Using simpleidn 0.2.1
Using jekyll-gist 1.5.0
Using dnsruby 1.61.9
Installing http_parser.rb 0.8.0 with native extensions
Installing eventmachine 1.2.7 with native extensions
Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions
Using ethon 0.15.0
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using typhoeus 1.4.0
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using listen 3.7.1
Using github-pages-health-check 1.17.9
Using sass 3.7.4
Using jekyll-watch 2.2.1
Using jekyll-sass-converter 1.5.2
Using em-websocket 0.5.3
Using jekyll 3.9.0
Using jekyll-commonmark-ghpages 0.2.0
Using jekyll-feed 0.15.1
Using jekyll-github-metadata 2.13.0
Using jekyll-redirect-from 0.16.0
Using jekyll-avatar 0.7.0
Using jekyll-remote-theme 0.4.3
Using jekyll-optional-front-matter 0.3.2
Using jekyll-sitemap 1.4.0
Using jekyll-readme-index 0.3.0
Using jekyll-include-cache 0.2.1
Using jekyll-relative-links 0.6.1
Using jekyll-mentions 1.6.0
Using jekyll-seo-tag 2.8.0
Using jekyll-default-layout 0.1.4
Using jekyll-titles-from-headings 0.5.3
Using jemoji 0.12.0
Using jekyll-theme-midnight 0.2.0
Using jekyll-theme-architect 0.2.0
Using jekyll-theme-cayman 0.2.0
Using jekyll-theme-dinky 0.2.0
Using jekyll-theme-slate 0.2.0
Using jekyll-theme-leap-day 0.2.0
Using jekyll-theme-merlot 0.2.0
Using jekyll-theme-minimal 0.2.0
Using jekyll-theme-modernist 0.2.0
Using jekyll-theme-primer 0.6.0
Using jekyll-theme-hacker 0.2.0
Using jekyll-theme-tactile 0.2.0
Using jekyll-theme-time-machine 0.2.0
Using minima 2.5.1
Using github-pages 225
Bundle complete! 6 Gemfile dependencies, 102 gems now installed.
Gems in the group 'production' were not installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

And as you can see it says `http_parser`, `eventmachine` and `ffi` are all being installed with no errors in the process.

But when I try to run `bundle exec jekyll build` in the same directory afterwards I get this error:

```bash
➜  <my-project> git:(main) ✗ bundle exec jekyll build
Could not find eventmachine-1.2.7, http_parser.rb-0.8.0, ffi-1.15.5 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Can anyone tell me why this might be happening and what I need to do to fix it?

I'm on macOS Ventura 13.0 (22A380)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's right at the top of your output:

```rb
Ignoring eventmachine-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine eventmachine --version 1.2.7
Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5
Ignoring http_parser.rb-0.8.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine http_parser.rb --version 0.8.0
Ignoring sassc-2.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine sassc --version 2.4.0
```

Try running those `pristine` commands.

Comment: I have totally done the same. And frankly, the gems being listed as `Installing` later on is very misleading.

Comment: Thank you! I had to run the command with `sudo`, without `sudo` it suggests `You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.`.

Comment: You can run `chmod +x /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0` to change/modify (chmod) your permissions to give yourself write access (+x) to that directory.